# Overwriting the free space on removable media with real data using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am in the process of creating a batch file to completely fill the remaining free space on USB drives, SD cards, Micro SD cards, etc... with real data in order to prevent the recovery of previously deleted files on the device.

Background:  I had a simple PNY brand 16GB SD card that was loaded with still photos taken by a hunting camera.  I deleted the photos with Windows 8 normal delete method.  I then used Windows 8 format feature (unchecking the "Quick Format" option) that supposedly securely erases the data.  Next, I ran my DiskDigger.exe program on the select drive and it retrieved every single photo.  I then ran Privazer.exe and performed a 3 Pass DoD overwrite on the SD card.  Still, DiskDigger retrieved every last photo.  With several more attempts at copying and pasting data to the card, then running secure erasing programs to remove the data, the photos were still retrievable.  The only way I was able to get the photos unretrievable was to overwrite every last byte on the SD card with a single 128 byte text file repeatedly copied until full.  When I reformatted the drive, the photos were no longer recoverable.

Sorry so exhaustive, but wanted everyone to know the exact problem.

What I want:

- .bat file to overwrite every byte of free space available on the media
- The overwrite data will be from a set of .txt files contained in same DIR
- Once executed, I do not want the .bat file to prompt user at all
- I do not want to run .bat file to the point I get disk full errors
- I want it to handle up to 64GB removeable drives

What I've got:

- F: just happens to be my particular USB drive letter
- No doubt this is millions of miles from efficient, but I was going 
  at it with a just get something to work approach.  It works until I
  get "Reached recursive SETLOCAL limit" (However, it filled the drive)
- I first generated .txt files of every standard size using a .bat file
  and loaded those in the same directory with my overwrite .bat file.
  It seems I cannot get a file larger than 2GB to copy using batch.
  Because of this, I have created 8 differently named 2GB text files
  to cover at least a 16GB SD card. Another problem I encountered
  was a prompt to the user to confirm overwrite of same file names.  I
  haven't figured out how to overcome that same file name prompt.
- I had to put all the SETLOCAL's just to get the For statements to
  accurately read the remaining free space.  Without them, the
  freespace variable remains the same for every iteration.

I know there a far better methods, but forgive me, that's what I'd like assistance with.  Can someone please

- Show me how to properly loop this
- If possible, show me how to force duplicate file names to still copy without prompting the user.  This will prevent me from having to create 32 differently named 2GB .txt files in order to overwrite a 64GB drive.
- I know it's rudimentary, but yes, I want it in batch.

This .bat file is supposed to read the free space from the drive, copy the largest .txt file that will fit into that space, reread the free space, copy the largest .txt file etc... until it completely fills the drive down to a space of 128 bytes without user input and without going to errors.

```
@echo off
Set "Blank=               "
Set "GB2=     2097152000"
Set "GB1=     1048576000"
Set "MB512=      524288000"
Set "MB256=      262144000"
Set "MB128=      131072000"
Set "MB64=       65536000"
Set "MB32=       32768000"
Set "MB16=       16384000"
Set "MB8=        8192000"
Set "MB4=        4096000"
Set "MB2=        2048000"
Set "MB1=        1024000"
Set "KB512=         512000"
Set "KB256=         256000"
Set "KB128=         128000"
Set "KB64=          64000"
Set "KB32=          32000"
Set "KB16=          16000"
Set "KB8=           8000"
Set "KB4=           4000"
Set "KB2=           2000"
Set "KB1=           1000"
Set "B512=            512"
Set "B256=            256"
Set "B128=            128"
Set "TB_10= 10995116277760"

for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set mydate=%%i
set mytime=%time%
echo Current time is %mydate%:%mytime%

:Loop
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%"
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 (1).txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%" 
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 (2).txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%" 
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 (3).txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%" 
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 (4).txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%" 
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 (5).txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%" 
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 (6).txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%" 
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 (7).txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%" 
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 (8).txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%" 
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB1%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes1.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB512%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes512.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB256%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes256.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB128%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes128.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB64%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes64.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB32%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes32.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB16%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes16.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB8%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes8.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB4%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes4.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes2.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB1%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes1.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB512%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes512.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB256%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes256.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB128%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes128.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB64%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes64.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB32%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes32.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB16%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes16.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB8%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes8.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB4%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes4.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes2.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB1%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes1.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%B512%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Bytes512.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%B256%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Bytes256.txt" F:
Echo File Copied
GOTO :Loop )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%B128%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Bytes128.txt" F:
Echo File Copied )
for /f "tokens=2" %%j in ('date /t') do set enddate=%%j
set endtime=%time%
echo Beginning time was %mydate%:%mytime%
echo Ending time was %enddate%:%endtime%
pause
```

The file runs

Comment: This question is way too broad. You need limit your questions in a single post.

Comment: Why re-inventing something other wrote already much better than you. A batch file is horrible slow for that task. There is for example free tool [sdelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) from Sysinternals (Microsoft) for filling a storage media with one or more write passes from command line. I use that tool from time to time, in an older version which does not display the EULA. Give `sdelete` a try. Perhaps it does the secure deletion better than the tools you have already tried.

Comment: One more hint: The manufacturers of flash based storage media offer often a special tool to secure delete their medias. This special tools from the manufacturers use really the flash chip erase command sequences for each flash chip inside the device and then recreate the file system on the device using firmware function calls which only those specialized tools know how to use them.

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard - I realize my post is extremely long winded; however, I do not think it is all that broad of a question.  It's probably one well written FOR statement for an expert that can then be called for every iteration.  I'm just not knowledgeable enough to figure it out.

Comment: @Mofi - I did not try 'sdelete' on that SD card.  The way I understood it, the Windows 8 'Format' feature without quick formatting was basically supposed to do what 'sdelete' does.  I will try it out though and see if it works differently.

Comment: I just finished attempting to use `sdelete64.exe -p 3 -z -c f:` on my SD card.  Unfortunately it got to 27% after half an hour and then hung there at 27% for another half hour before I stopped it.  I'll try again later.

Comment: Considering that you wanted to wipe the free space with a non secure method by a batch file, specifying three passes for `sdelete` is way overkill. It just makes the process extremely and unnecessarily slow. Just one pass suffices to make the data irrecoverable. Software can not recover data from a correctly overwritten medium(unless the medium has physical issues which extra passes may not help either), data recovery from such a medium, if at all possible, requires highly specialized equipment (hardware and software).

Comment: Even those who want to destroy highly sensitive data, prefer to destroy the device physically (burning, melting,...) instead of overwriting the medium with many passes. It is better to do a check disk before executing sdelete: `chkdsk /f f:` to reclaim any unused spaces which may have incorrectly marked as used space because of file system errors. It may even help to pass over the `sdelete` hang.

Comment: @sst  I'm not sure why writing specific text to all available space is considered non secure.  I did take your suggestions and performed the `chkdsk /f f:` and reran the `sdelete` on single pass only.  I got zero disk errors in the `chkdsk` but for some reason the `sdelete64.exe` I am using still hung up at 27%,  I think I will still incorporate a `chkdsk` in my routine.  Great suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a working solution that accomplishes the task of overwriting the free space on a removeable media with real text data.  The .bat program runs on my laptop from start to finish without user input or errors.

Using a blank 16GB SD card through a USB card adapter, I compared my run time againt CCleaner.

- My .bat file took 33 minutes to COMPLETELY fill the SD card with text data.
- CCleaner set on '1 pass pseudorandom data' took 32 minutes.

I was fairly impressed with the comparison to the big commercial brand.  I know this .bat file is writing data to every available free space on the drive; however, I'm not positive that the 1 pass pseudorandom CCleaner does the same.  I can also be assured that this .bat file does not phone home, collect user data, or keep statistics on me.  This is my reason for choosing to write a .bat file rather than going with someone else's commercial brand.  There's no ads, no pop ups, no hidden connections to the internet, etc...

If anyone wants to actually use this program, I can post a copy of the .bat file I used to generate my specifically sized .txt files that were used as fill data.  Just message me and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

This following is my .bat program.  I tried to comment it the best I could.  I am still wide open to suggestions on shrinking it or streamlining it for better efficiency.  I'm no expert, this is just where I'm at right now with batch.  The time caalculation doesn't come out correct at the end. I guess you can't just simple subtract beginning time from end time.  I will work on it.  It doesn't error though.

```
::  THIS BATCH FILE FILLS THE REMAINING FREE SPACE OF A DRIVE WITH PREDETERMINED
::  USER CREATED DATA FILES OF SPECIFIC BYTE LENGTHS EQUALING THE LENGTHS SHOWN
::  BELOW IN THE VARIABLE INITIALIZATIONS.  
@echo off
Set "Blank=               "
Set "GB64=    67108864000"
Set "GB32=    33554432000"   
Set "GB16=    16777216000"
Set "GB8=     8388608000"
Set "GB4=     4194304000"
Set "GB2=     2097152000"
Set "GB1=     1048576000"
Set "MB512=      524288000"
Set "MB256=      262144000"
Set "MB128=      131072000"
Set "MB64=       65536000"
Set "MB32=       32778000"
Set "MB16=       16384000"
Set "MB8=        8192000"
Set "MB4=        4096000"
Set "MB2=        2048000"
Set "MB1=        1024000"
Set "KB512=         512000"
Set "KB256=         256000"
Set "KB128=         128000"
Set "KB64=          64000"
Set "KB32=          32000"
Set "KB16=          16000"
Set "KB8=           8000"
Set "KB4=           4000"
Set "KB2=           2000"
Set "KB1=           1000"
Set "B512=            512"
Set "B256=            256"
Set "B128=            128"

::  GET THE FILE EXECUTION START TIME

set StartTime=%time%
echo Start time is %StartTime%
echo.

::  GET THE CURRENT AMOUNT OF FREE SPACE ON THE REMOVEABLE MEDIA (CHANGE DRIVE LETTER AS APPROPRIATE)

for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"

::  LIMIT THE VARIABLE TO 15 DIGITS

Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"

::  PRINT INITIAL FREE SPACE IN TERMINAL WINDOW

echo Amount of intial free space to be filled = %FreeSpace%
echo.

::  BEGIN PROCESS OF NARROWING DOWN FREE SPACE BY COPYING LARGEST FILES FIRST THEN INCREMENTALLY SMALLER ONES

If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB64%" ( call :TooLarge )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( call :Over2MB )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB1%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes1.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB512%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes512.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB256%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes256.txt" F:
call :ReCalculate )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB128%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes128.txt" F:
call :ReCalculate )
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB64%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes64.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB32%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes32.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB16%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes16.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB8%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes8.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB4%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes4.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes2.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%MB1%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Megabytes1.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB512%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes512.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB256%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes256.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB128%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes128.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB64%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes64.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB32%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes32.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB16%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes16.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB8%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes8.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB4%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes4.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB2%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes2.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%KB1%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Kilobytes1.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%B512%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Bytes512.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%B256%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Bytes256.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%B128%" ( xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Bytes128.txt" F: 
call :ReCalculate)

echo. 
echo.
echo.
echo ---------Amount of free space remaining on drive f: = %FreeSpace%----------
echo.
echo.
setlocal
set StopTime=%time%
set /a CompletionTime=%StopTime%-%StartTime%
echo Total execution time was %CompletionTime% 
echo.
echo.
pause
exit /b

::  RECALCULATE FREE SPACE AFTER EACH FILE IS COPIED

:ReCalculate

for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
goto :eof


::  PERFORM COPY OF MORE THAN ONE 2MB FILE, IF NECESSARY, BY RENAMING THE FILE TO BE COPIED
::  SO AS TO AVOID A 'FILE ALREADY EXISTS' USER PROMPT

:Over2MB

set /a Counter=Counter+1
xcopy "c:\Batch Files\File Builder\Gigabytes2 ("%Counter%").txt" F:
echo File Copied "%Counter%" times.
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('wmic LogicalDisk Get DeviceID^,FreeSpace ^| find /i "F:"') Do Set "FreeSpace=%Blank%%%A"
Set "FreeSpace=%FreeSpace:~-15%"
Echo FreeSpace="%FreeSpace%"
If "%FreeSpace%" gtr "%GB2%" ( goto :Over2MB ) 
goto :eof

::  INFORM USER THAT THE DRIVE SPACE EXCEEDS THE CAPABILITIES OF THIS BATCH FILE 

:TooLarge

echo.
echo.
echo This program is limited to devices 64 MB or less.
echo.
echo.
echo --------------- PROGRAM ENDED ------------------
echo.
echo.
pause
exit /b
```